# Jquery form submission happening to parent URL instead of modal specified URL

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a Jquery based Submit button.

I have the following code for from submission.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $myForm = $('.flag-post-form')
    $myForm.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        var $formData = $(this).serialize()
        var $thisURL = $myForm.attr('data-url') || window.location.href // or set your own url
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: $thisURL,
            data: $formData,
            success: handleFormSuccess,
            error: handleFormError,
        })
    })

    function handleFormSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log(data)
        console.log(textStatus)
        console.log(jqXHR)
        //$myForm.reset(); // reset form data
         $('.report-post-btn').attr("disabled", true);
        if(data['message']){
        $( ".modal-errors").html("<h3 class='text-center text-success'>"+data['message']+"</h3>")}
        else{
          $( ".modal-errors").html("<h3 class='text-center text-success'>"+"Successfully reported post"+"</h3>")
        }
    }

    function handleFormError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(jqXHR)
        console.log(textStatus)
        console.log(errorThrown)
        $( ".modal-errors").html("<h3 class='text-center text-danger'>Unable to report post. Try again!</h3>")
    }
})
</script>
```

The following code inside bootstrap modal that is dynamically loaded from external URL.

```
<form data-url="/forum/flag_post/0838024b-f210-4f4d-ac53-fd4ade12d533" method="POST" id="flag-post-form" class="flag-post-form form" action="."><input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="N7PNVNJ05lEq62cl4L9wRYkrmH8hPjuSBec1PVVNRaCXmJ4oZIjJ57EtlBiljV8s" type="hidden">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Enter reason below and report Post</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <input name="reason" maxlength="200" class="form-control" id="id_reason" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-errors"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input class="btn btn-primary report-post-btn" value="Report Post" type="submit">
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </form>
```

When I load the modal the first time, the submit happens using Jquery and to the URL specified in `data-url`.

However once I load the modal the second time, the submission happens to the URL in which the modal is loaded, i.e, the URL in which the modal is loaded.

I'm unable to figure out what changed the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your modal form is dynamically loaded, the event binding is likely lost once the modal is dismissed.  In the code you provided you're only binding to the form's `submit` event once, when the document's `ready` event fires.  Consider using jQuery's `.on()` method, binding to a parent node that will always be present on the page.

```
$('body').on('submit', '.flag-post-form', function(event) {
   // ... your submit event handler code here ...
});
```

More information here:  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Should I use `$('body').on('submit', '.flag-post-form', function(event) {` instead of `$myForm.submit(function(event){` Will this replace work?

Comment: How ever now I have two submissions happening.

Can you convert my example into the solution you provided?